# Design tabhost in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-tabhost

I have a question that I think is really easy answer if you know, how to I change the visible tab in Eclipse while developing the GUI in Ecplise?

I can add tabs and add stuff to the outline and change it but I can't figure out how to change what Tab that is visible in the development view, I can only see the first tab...

(If I move the tab I'm about to develop to first position the I can see you not the right way I guess?)

Have search google and forum but no luck so far.

Thanks in advance
Best regards 
Oskar Norin
Sweden

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see of how to go about doing this is to create each tab in its own xml layout file and then join them together using the include tag in the xml to link to that tab.

Something like:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/tab4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/tab4" />
```

This way you just switch to the layout you want to design and it gets included automatically. Not ideal but it works.